# flip line order assembly 32bit

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I need to flip line order of a file and write them in another file, but I have some problems.I can't write in file2 for some reason...Any advice and hint will be useful,it's my first problem of this type.A hint from my teacher was to use fseek and i used that but im stuck.

example:

input file1:

```
line1
line 2
line 3
```

desired output file2:

```
line 3
line2
line 1
```

```
    .386
    .model flat, stdcall
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    ;includem biblioteci, si declaram ce functii vrem sa importam
    includelib msvcrt.lib
    extern exit: proc
    extern fopen:proc
    extern getc:proc
    extern fclose:proc
    extern printf:proc
    extern ftell:proc
    extern fseek:proc
    extern fscanf:proc
    extern fprintf: proc
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    ;declaram simbolul start ca public - de acolo incepe executia
    public start
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    ;sectiunile programului, date, respectiv cod
    .data
    ;aici declaram date
    s db 99 dup(0)
    read db "r",0
    write db "w",0
    nume db "fisier1.txt",0
    nume2 db "fisier2.txt",0
    seek_end dd 2
    format db "%s",0
    .code

    start:
        ;open first file to read
        push offset read
        push offset nume
        call fopen
        add esp,8
        mov esi,eax;save pointer of file

        ;open second file to write
        push offset write
        push offset nume2
        call fopen
        add esp,8
        mov edi,eax;save pointer of file

        ;find the end of file
        push seek_end
        push -1
        push esi
        call fseek
        add esp,12

        ;save in ecx current position
        push esi
        call ftell
        add esp,4
        mov ecx,eax

        et:
            push esi
            call getc
            add esp,4
            cmp eax,0ah;verify if isn't new line
            jne previous
            previous:
                ;move to the previous line
                push 1
                push -1
                push esi
                call fseek
                add esp,12
                jmp cont
            read_write:
                ;read the line in string s 
                push offset s
                push offset format
                push esi
                call fscanf
                add esp,12

                ;print string s in second file
                push offset s
                push offset format
                push edi
                call fprintf
                add esp,12

                jmp previous

        cont:
            dec ecx
            ;verify if isn't the beginning of file  
            cmp ecx,0
            jne et

        push 0
        call exit
    end start
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this program?  `fisier2.txt` is created by your 2nd `fopen` function call, right?  Then you seek to the input of your input file and try to read from there, returning EOF because you're at the end.  Also, ECX is a call-clobbered register in the calling convention you're using, so expect every library `call` to destroy it.  Use `ebx` for your counter or something.  Anyway, this isn't a [mcve] because you haven't shown what happens.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Your teacher's hint to use `lseek` was probably to use it to find the length of the file to find out how big a buffer you need, then seek back to the start.  Then read the whole input file, and loop backwards over the buffer, printing lines when you find a newline.

Comment: Sorry the hint from teacher was fseek,the file is created with succes and the reading from file1 it's fine but writing in file2 doesn't work from some reason

Comment: `fseek` makes more sense, given that you're using other C stdio functions, and that fseek to the end + `ftell` is the only ISO C way to find file length.  But then don't forget to `fseek` back to the start.  If you had `lseek` available, you'd use `stat` or `fstat`.  Anyway, use a debugger to find out what does happen as you step through your program, and which functions succeed and which return errors.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz: OS doesn't matter for once; the OP appears to only be using ISO C stdio functions with a 32-bit stack-args calling convention, and that should be sufficient to debug.  But from the masm32 tag, we can be confident it's Windows.

Comment: @PeterCordes Calling convention could be an issue, which is why I ask.

Comment: @fuz: ok that's fair, it could be Windows with a callee-pops convention in which case every `push` + `call` + `add esp, n` would be clearing more and more bytes from the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes It could be some UNIX-like system with mandatory stack alignment.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely something I would not write in assembly language... However, to do that work, I would first write the algorithm in a high level language. If you can get the logic to work properly in a higher level language, you can then make your assembly work.

```
in = fopen("source.txt", "r");
fseek(in, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(in);
fseek(in, 0, SEEK_SET);
out = fopen("destination.txt", "w");
ftruncate(out, size);
fseek(out, 0, SEEK_END);
while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), in))
{
    len = strlen(buf);
    fseek(out, -len, SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(out, 1, len, buf);
    fseek(out, -len, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

This function has a limit on the size of a line determined by `sizeof(buf)` and there is a bug in that one line:

> the `fgets()` does not return a null terminated string if it can read `sizeof(buf)` bytes.

This is how bad the C library is, unfortunately. A simple fix for that bug:

```
buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';
...
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, in)
```

i.e. You place a `'\0'` at the end of the buffer and never overwrite it. So at least you never overrun your buffer.

Now for you to convert that C code in assembly.

Also first understand your algorithm before doing actual real coding.

Note: I did not test for any error codes either. Error handling is a good idea. (i.e. what if `fopen("destination.txt"...)` fails?)

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess we can take advantage of the output file being a regular file as well, and seek in it.  In comments on the question I suggested reading the entire input file into memory and writing the output in order.  Too bad `fgets` doesn't return the number of bytes read; that's just dumb and would mean you could easily loop until you'd copied a full line.  Then the design would just be weird, not a bug.

Comment: @PeterCordes, `fgets()` in itself is not a bug, but the use of it, I'm sure, created an unlimited number of bugs that could have been avoided if only it could have put a `'\0'` as the last character no matter what... At least they fixed that on in C++ (where they even remove the `'\n'` character!)

Comment: Ok, yeah, not a bug, but it knows how many bytes it read and simply chooses to return one of its input args while throwing away that useful data.  That's just stupid, so you have to call `strlen` if you need the length.  C stdio and string functions often seem to discard useful info, as if the people designing them weren't thinking about asm / efficiency of looping multiple times over the same data.  Sometimes you don't care and `strcat` is convenient, but sometimes you do...  Anyway, storing the `\n` does let you tell whether you read a whole line or not, so that's useful.